# two versions of svn

Tags: macos, svn

But, mac os x comes with 1.6 version of svn. I wanted to update my version of svn, so I installed svn using

```
brew install svn
```

which installed svn version 1.7

But if I try to check my svn version using

```
svn --version
```

It still shows 1.6

How can I change which installation to use?

(Note: It was very difficult to find right words to google this question.)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2534459/422353) is about different versions but the solution might still be valid.

Comment: no, that solution did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use `which svn` to see the path to your svn executable. If it isn't your brew install directory (*/usr/local* by default), you'll need to change your PATH variable so it looks in your brew install directory before the directory where it's currently finding `svn`. `echo $PATH` will show you your current path search list. Edit your ~/.bash_profile and look at all the statements that create the PATH variable. Edit or rearrange them so your desired path winds up before the current path.

Comment: well I did. port install subversion. That installed one more version of svn on my mac. It seems like "port > default > brew"

Answer (score 1):

I did

```
port install subversion
```

This command installed one more version of svn on my mac.

And it seems priority is like

> macports installation > default mac installation > brew installation

So, I did not try to get my brew's svn on the top, instead I accidentally installed something (macports svn) which overridden the default installation of svn. So, my mac has 3 svns, but only 1.7 is used now.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem and I think my PATH env variable is correct.

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin
```

I don't know why but I solved the problem by renaming the system svn to other.

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/svn /usr/bin/svn.old
```